# Error “500 behavior::tabstate not found.” when trying to access SP Page Builder

Tags: php, templates, extensions, joomla-4

I am currently using Joomla 4.0.0 Beta 6 with Helix Ultimate 2.0.0 Alpha 3 and PHP 7.2. My website runs on LiteSpeed Web Server, NOT Apache.

When I go to The Joomla administrator panel > SP Page Builder > Pages, I get the following error:

```
"An error has occurred.
500 behavior::tabstate not found."
```

Here is what I got in the logs file:

*CRITICAL ..... error Uncaught Throwable of type InvalidArgumentException thrown with message "behavior::tabstate not found.". Stack trace: #0 ~/public_html/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/sppagebuilder.php(18): Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper::_('jhtml.behavior....')*

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Download the Helix Ultimate Quickstart Package at https://www.joomshaper.com/downloads/template/helixultimate and upload it to your website's public_html folder.
2. Unzip the package file.
3. Go to [www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php](http://www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php) and follow the installation procedures.
4. Upgrade Helix Ultimate to 2.0.0 Alpha 3 (The download link: https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.3) and Joomla! to 4.0.0 Beta 6.

The above problem DOESN'T HAPPEN when following these steps:

1. Download Joomla! in your website and update it to version 4 Beta 6.
2. Download and install Helix Ultimate 2 Alpha 3 and set it as the default site template (https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-alpha.3).
3. Download and install the free version of SP Page Builder (Lite version) (https://www.joomshaper.com/downloads/extension/sp-page-builder-free).
4. Import the database information of Helix Ultimate Quickstart Package to your website.
5. Change your website's configuration.php file to match the information of the imported database.
6. Update the SP Page Builder Database via the website's administrator control panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the above problem solved after using Helix Ultimate 2 Beta 2 Quickstart Package (https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/download/v2.0.0-beta.2/helixultimate_2_beta2_quickstart.zip).

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Download the Helix Ultimate Quickstart Package at https://github.com/JoomShaper/helix-ultimate/releases/tag/v2.0.0-beta.2 and upload it to your website's public_html folder.
2. Unzip the package file.
3. Go to [www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php](http://www.yoursitename.com/installation/index.php) and follow the installation procedures.
4. Upgrade your site to Joomla 4 Beta 7.